# gamepad force feedback (vibration) on windows using raw input

Tags: c, input, vibration, gamepad

I'm currently writing a cross platform library in C which includes gamepad support. Gamepad communication on windows is handled by both raw input and xinput, depending on the specific gamepad.

While xinput facilitates force feedback on xbox360 controllers, I have not found a way to do this using raw input. I have some gamepads that can give force feedback, but I cannot find a way to do this through raw input. Is there a way to do this?

I prefer not to use the directinput api, since it's deprecated and discouraged by Microsoft.

Edit:

Since I've implemented gamepads for a large part, maybe I can narrow down the question a bit. I suspect the amount of rumble motors in a gamepad can be found by reading the NumberOutputValueCaps of a HIDP_CAPS structure. This gives the correct result for all my test gamepads.

I'm using the funtcion HidP_GetUsageValue to read axis values, which works fine. Now I suspect calling HidP_SetUsageValue should allow me to change this output value, turning on the rumble motor. Calling this function fails, however. Should this function be able to access rumble motors?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HidP_SetUsageValue() only modifies a report buffer -- you need to first prepare an appropriately-sized buffer (which may be why the function was failing; input reports and output reports won't necessarily be the same size) then send it to the device before it will have any effect.  MSDN suggests you can use HidD_SetOutputReport() for that purpose, but I had better luck with WriteFile(), following the sample code at: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/HClient-HID-Sample-4ec99697/sourcecode?fileId=51262&pathId=340791466

This snippet (based on the Linux driver) lets me control the motors and LED on a DualShock 4:

```
const char *path = /* from GetRawInputDeviceInfo(RIDI_DEVICENAME) */;
HANDLE hid_device = CreateFile(path, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                               FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL,
                               OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
assert(hid_device != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
uint8_t buf[32];
memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
buf[0] = 0x05;
buf[1] = 0xFF;
buf[4] = right_motor_strength;  // 0-255
buf[5] = left_motor_strength;   // 0-255
buf[6] = led_red_level;         // 0-255
buf[7] = led_green_level;       // 0-255
buf[8] = led_blue_level;        // 0-255
DWORD bytes_written;
assert(WriteFile(hid_device, buf, sizeof(buf), &bytes_written, NULL));
assert(bytes_written == 32);
```

(EDIT: fixed buffer offsets)